# Environment Variables not set on first boot of Android Studio, but set on subsequent launches

Tags: macos, android-studio, environment-variables, launch

I'm passing `ANDROID_NDK` and my PATH to Android Studio in my `~/.profile` file using:

```
launchctl setenv ANDROID_NDK $ANDROID_NDK
```

and using
`sudo launchctl config user path $PATH`

However when I boot my Mac, the first launch of Android Studio does not have `ANDROID_NDK`, or my PATH set. Then I close Android Studio and reopen it, they're set.

`ANDROID_NDK` is set in my terminal environment, and obviously works when I boot Android Studio from the terminal.

I have duplicated the behaviour in IntelliJ and TortoiseHG for what it's worth.

I'm on High Sierra 10.13.6, Android Studio 3.5.3

EDIT: `launchctl dumpstate` shows android.studio using:

```
default environment = {
        no ANDROID_NDK
    }

inherited environment = {
        ANDROID_NDK => **correct
}
environment = {
        no ANDROID_NDK
}
```

So it's inherited but not set correctly?